# What is the differences between rndc and manually manipulating named.conf.local

Tags: dns, bind

I know rndc means that I can control the dns server from remote. However, let's say I don't need such remote feature. I do everything on the dns server. What I wanted to is to efficiently add/update/remove zones without affecting other zones. I figured out some script using rndc to add/update/remove zones like so:

to add a new zone

```
rndc addzone mydomain.com  '{type master; file "/etc/bind/db.mydomain.com";};'
rndc reconfig
```

to reload modified zone

```
rndc reload mydomain.com
```

to remove a zone

```
rndc delzone mydomain.com
```

It seems to be quite handy. However, it seems it doesn't add anything to the named.conf.local file. So does it mean rndc has taken over the control from the usual named.conf.local way? If this is the case, what are the differences? Which way should I use?

Thanks,
Elgs

Comment: This is kinda off-topic for StackOverflow and should be moved to SuperUser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, to use this feature, you have to enable it, so in your options block in `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` I assume you have:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    ...
    allow-new-zones yes;
    ...
}
```

When you use `rndc addzone`, the server will create a new file called `<hashstring>.nzf` in the base directory as specified above.  The < hashstring > is a hash of the view name.  Anyway, this file is re-read when you start up the name server again after stopping it, or rebooting, so the changes persist.

If you're happy with the way this works, stick with it.  The only downside is all your zone specifications are not all in named.conf.local so you'll have two files to look in if you need to modify any zone options.

Comment: Thanks @milli. If I use the traditional name.conf.local way, does it mean I have to restart bind9 whenever any zone file changes. What I know is I can apply changes using `rndc reload mydomain.com`, and it's pretty fast.

Comment: If you are just adding/removing zones, use `rndc reconfig` which is much faster than `rndc reload`.
If you change zone options then use `rndc reload`.
If you only change the zone contents of a non-dynamic zone you can use `rndc reload <zone>`.  But I always use `rndc freeze <zone>`, make record changes, then `rndc thaw <zone>` as I have a lot of zones that allow dynamic updates and several zones that are DNSSEC-signed, so those have journals that need to be synced on disk before you make manual edits.

Comment: thank you very much. The information you provided is invaluable to me.